# Why was Deadpool dishonorably discharged?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

In the movie, when Ajax was explaining to Wade how they were going to torture him next, he mentions that Wade was dishonorably discharged. There does not seem to be much information on what the actual reason for him being so.

Ajax mentions this around 0:42

Although he seemed to have been an assassin, as stated by [Marvel Universe Wiki](https://www.marvel.com/characters/deadpool-wade-wilson)

> Following a brief stint of military service, Wade began his mercenary career while still in his late teens. Accepting assassination jobs only against those whom he felt deserved death, he made a habit of using plastic surgery and technology to take on a new identity whenever he failed an assignment.

**Why was Wade dishonorably discharged from the Army?**

Comment: It's not stated in the movie or, apparently, in the comics. Indeed, Deadpool's origins have been re-written, overwritten and depend entirely on who's writing which comic version at any one time.

Comment: You figure he talked too much? Couldn't keep his mouth shut? Pissed off his captains and commanders?

Comment: They confused him with Slade Wilson

Comment: My guess is that Wade Wilson being Wade Wilson, he was such a complete jerkass to his superiors that they booted him out.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I asked my good friend [Fabian Nicieza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabian_Nicieza) (co-creator of Deadpool) what incident resulted in Wade being ejected from the military.

I am advised that this element wasn't part of his original backstory and was added by another, later writer.

> **Q.** *Quick question. What did Wade Wilson get dishonorably discharged for?*
>
> **FN:** *Since [the] answer depends on [which] writer or editor you ask, there is no "real" answer*
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter: 27 Aug 2016](https://twitter.com/FabianNicieza/status/769495535858384896?lang=en-gb)</sup></sub>

Answer (score -3):

If I were asked to write a background to his dishonorable discharge and being a former military member, it goes like this in my mind

- Wade Wilson was a member of the special forces and he lists several places around the world he has been, then finishes his statement with Jacksonville... I am assuming (for me personally) that he was in the Navy or Marines as there is a large naval station in Jacksonville, Florida.  Seeing his personality traits before he was mutated showed he enjoyed humor to disarm anyone he was confronting and I think to help him self stay focused on his objective.
- He also had a short fuse and I think he used Humor to keep himself in check.  He had an ethics code where he didn't mind starting conflicts with people he thought could handle them or deserved them, but he also felt obligated to protect those that need to be protected
- He wouldn't harm anyone that didn't deserve it in his mind.  I think he was enlisted and used his wit, aggressiveness and humor on an officer in his group that he felt deserved it. (example.. Wade deflected further torture to his bunk mate in the torture chamber where he was with other individuals who were being tested on, by directing Ajax's attention from Campbell(?) to himself by calling Ajax by his first name of Francis}.  I think Wade directed an officer's attention from a team mate to himself, then proceeded to teach the Officer a lesson with intimidation, aggression, humor and finally physical force.  Has was then given an Artical 15, court martial, and a dishonorable discharge.  I don't think this really bothered him as he had a hard time with following orders but liked doing the job he did, so he converted to being a mercenary and took his military skills and experience with him.

I know long answer, but a question that I found intriguing and answered for myself, since I too couldn't find a history of his discharge.

Answer (score -4):

In a moment in the films he says he tried being a hero “once”. He probably got discharged for doing the right thing but not what he was ordered to do.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for your speculation?